# Shopping Cart Price Rule - Configurable Product Buy X get Y Discount

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like to know if there is a solution to this with Magento out of the box without any extensions.

We are a Configurable/Simple product association apparel e-commerce site.

I want to set up buy 2 of any simple product associated with a configurable product and get $X off.

Another example: Buy 2 Baseball Tee's and get $X off.

We have numerous simple product associated with the Baseball Tee and when you add in your shopping cart 1 white small baseball tee and 1 black medium baseball tee the shopping cart rule doesn't apply because of the "Discount Qty Step (Buy X)" field in the shopping cart price rule set up is only associated with a single simple item and not a configurable item, therefore you have to add 2 of the same exact items for the discount to apply. We want this discount to work in multiples of 2, so get 2 of these baseball tees and get $8 off then 4 tees is $16 off, etc.

Does anyone know a work around to make this work? Would like to stay away from altering code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At the conditions tab select

Total qty of products = 2 with following conditions:
Sku is one of a,b,c

At the actions tab select
Action: fixed amount for whole cart
Amount: x

For 2,4,8 create multiple rules.

Don't know other solution without extensions or custom development